# Unable to start Kanela Agent because of missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64', need 'arm64')

Tags: scala, apple-m1

I’m struggling to run an scala application on my M1 mac, I’ve ran this same application in the past using a java version for the x86_64 architecture due to some other limitations in the project. Now I’m supposed to run my project using arm64 architecture but I’m getting the following error with sbt run:

```
[Attach Listener] ERROR 2023-11-02 11:01:18  Logger : Unable to start Kanela Agent. Please remove -javaagent from your startup arguments and contact Kanela support.: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/mauricio.reis/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna8601538835774206176.tmp: dlopen(/Users/mauricio.reis/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna8601538835774206176.tmp, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/mauricio.reis/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna8601538835774206176.tmp' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/mauricio.reis/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna8601538835774206176.tmp' (no such file), '/Users/mauricio.reis/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna8601538835774206176.tmp' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64', need 'arm64'))
```

I’ve already uninstalled java multiple times

```
mauricio.reis@TDF69CFXXL scorm-admin % java -version 
openjdk version "1.8.0_392"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.74.0.17-CA-macos-aarch64) (build 1.8.0_392-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.74.0.17-CA-macos-aarch64) (build 25.392-b08, mixed mode)
```

and sbt as well

```
mauricio.reis@TDF69CFXXL scorm-admin % sbt --version
sbt version in this project: 1.3.13
sbt script version: 1.9.7
```

I also deleted .ivy2 .sbt .m2 on my home folder and also the ~/Library/Caches/Coursier/ folder

Do you know what else could I try?

Comment: If the dylib you wanna load into Java doesn't support arm64, then you need to install x86_64 Java and run it under Rosetta.

Comment: I have a colleague that can run the same project on his M1 machine, I'm suspecting that this issue is happening with me because I ran this project using x86_64 Java in  the past on this machine (no longer an option now a days) and he didn't. That's why I was deleting every cache and dot folder that I could find that could be related to the project.